# Extra leading zeros when printing float using printf?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, formatting, printf

I'd like to be able to write a time string that looks like this: `1:04:02.1 hours` using printf.
When I try to write something like this:

```
printf("%d:%02d:%02.1f hours\n", 1, 4, 2.123456);
```

I get:

```
1:04:2.1 hours
```

Is it possible to add leading zeros to a float formatting?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With the `%f` format specifier, the "2" is treated as the minimum number of characters altogether, not the number of digits before the decimal dot. Thus you have to replace it with 4 to get two leading digits + the decimal point + one decimal digit.

```
printf("%d:%02d:%04.1f hours\n", 1, 4, 2.123456);
```

Comment: having this for non-floats is also nice !

Answer (score 24):

Try `%04.1f` instead of `%02.1f`. The "4" here means at least 4 characters will be printed, and "2.1" has 3 (> 2) characters, so to enable the padding zeros you need 4.

Comment: How about negative numbers? I'd want sth like: `-00.1`

Comment: First, turn it to positive `f = fabsf(f)`, then `-0%.1f`. This works well for `f<10`. For `f>10` -> its like `-010.3`. I don't want the leading `0`: `-10.3`. Any better ideas?