# PHP integer part padding

Tags: java, php, floating-point, numbers, pad

I need to pad the integer part with 0, the integer part must be at least 2 characters

```
str_pad( 2    ,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);// 02 -> works
str_pad( 22   ,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);// 22 -> works
str_pad( 222  ,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);// 222-> works
str_pad( 2.   ,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);// 2. -> fails -> 02. or 02
str_pad( 2.11 ,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);// 2.11-> fails -> 02.11
```

Is there simple code for that?

If possible the same in Java please

```
double x=2.11;
String.format("%02d%s", (int) x, String.valueOf(x-(int) x).substring(1))
```

is not only ugly but prints 02.10999999999999988

*edit* for Java: [Java integer part padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383859/java-integer-part-padding)

Comment: str_pad is working on strings. You should split the integer and decimal parts before applying str_pad to the integer part then appending the decimal part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `printf()` functions to pad the integer :

Something like ([codepad](http://codepad.org/FiNeA2mf)):

```
<?php

function pad($n) {
    $n = explode('.', (string)$n);

    if (2 === count($n)) {
        return sprintf("%02d.%d\n", $n[0], $n[1]);    
    }

    return sprintf("%02d\n", $n[0]);    
}

foreach (array(2, 22, 222, 2., 2.11) as $num) {
    echo pad($num);
}

// returns 02, 22, 222, 02, 02.11
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no simple way.

```
function padIntegerPart($n, $len) {
    $intPart = (int)$n;

    return str_repeat('0', max(0, $len - 1 - floor(log($intPart, 10)))) . $n;
}
```

Comment: `sprintf` with a `%*f`, by the way, will only work with a fixed decimal place. (Why can't I comment on other answers?)

Comment: I think you need more reputation.

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution: http://codepad.org/EXcbqGos

```
$num = 2.11;
echo str_pad( floor($num) ,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).substr($num-floor($num), 1);
```

It will only work for non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If the output you're looking for is `02.11`, then try `sprintf()`:

```
sprintf("%05.2f", 02.11); // Output: 02.11
           ^ ^--- float precision
           |--- total string length

sprintf("%07.2f", 02.11); // Output: 0002.11
```

Links that may help are:

https://www.php.net/sprintf

[Extra leading zeros when printing float using printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486410/extra-leading-zeros-when-printing-float-using-printf)

Answer (score 0):

Another one :

```
function my_str_pad ($input ,$pad_length, $pad_string) {
    $pad_length += strlen($input) - strlen(intval($input));

    return str_pad($input, $pad_length, $pad_string, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

The following test :

```
str_pad(2., 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);// 2. -> fails -> 02. or 02
```

Fails because str_pad is working on a string, but you entered a number with a decimal but no decimal part so it is considered as an integer. If you want to keep the '.' use the following instead :

```
str_pad("2.", 2, "0" , STR_PAD_LEFT);// 2. -> works
```