# Java integer part padding

Tags: java, numbers, format, pad

Sorry I was initially wanting to do it in php [PHP integer part padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383597/php-java-integer-part-padding), but realised I will do it in Java in another part of code

So I need to format numbers with the integer part at  least 2 chars

2.11 -> 02.11
22.11 -> 22.11
222.11 -> 222.11
2.1111121 -> 02.1111121

```
double x=2.11; 
System.out.println(String.format("%08.5f", x));
```

could do it, but it's annoying the right trailing zeros, I would like to have an arbitrary large floating part

```
String.format("%02d%s", (int) x, String.valueOf(x-(int) x).substring(1))
```

is totally ugly and unexact (gives  02.1099...)

```
new DecimalFormat("00.#############").format(x)
```

will truncate floating part

thx for any better solutions

Comment: change it to `String.format("%8.5f", x)` (without the 0 before the 8).

Comment: I need to pad integer part with 0, to have at least 2 characters for integer part

Comment: then change it to `String.format("%02.5f", x)`, if the number has more than 2 digits in the integer part, it will print the whole integer part.

Comment: it gives 2.11000, I need 02.11

Comment: Are you aware of how many digits do you need on the decimal part? Because you can use `String.format("%02f", x)` without problems. I guess you should put more examples about what you need/want. You can even use a [`NumberFormat`](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html) object to do the job for you (but it will require more lines of code)

Comment: You also need to be aware of the semantics of a J

Comment: Yes NumberFormat with 00.# seems close, but I don,t really want to truncate floating part 05.33231554255 for ex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best I could come with is

```
public static String pad(String s){
    String[] p = s.split("\\.");
    if (2 == p.length){
        return String.format("%02d.%s", Integer.parseInt(p[0]), p[1]);
    }
    return String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(p[0]));
}
```

pad(String.valueOf(1.11111118)) -> 01.11111118

Answer (score -1):

Here's an one-liner using DecimalFormat:

```
new DecimalFormat("00." + (x + "").replaceAll(".", "#")).format(x)
```

It formats your decimal as 00.#############..., where the length of "#############..." comes from the length of your decimal ("#"s in excess does nothing).

You can use `String.valueOf(x)` in place of `(x + "")` if you wish.

Comment: I'd prefer not truncate, to not lose accuracy

Comment: yes nice, like new DecimalFormat("00." + StringUtils.repeat("#", (x+"").length())).format(x)

Comment: "#'s in excess does nothing": try this: float f = (float) 22.2222;
  System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("00." + (""+f).replaceAll(".", "#")).format(f));

Comment: # isn't the cause. Y'know, doubles and floats are limited in all programing languages. And even, that limitation varies according to where and how you use the value. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1420758/1493676), answered by Stack Overflow's #1 Jon Skeet, as well as his [famous talk](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) about many cases like that.