# C formatted string - How to add leading zeros to float and int values?

Tags: c, formatting, placeholder, output, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extra leading zeros when printing float using printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486410/extra-leading-zeros-when-printing-float-using-printf)

I'm trying to get the output of this C program to have placeholder zeros, as the output of this program will be used as input for another program. Right now, I'm using the following print line.

```
fprintf(fp1, "06 BR%d%d   %3.4f%3.4f%3.4f\n",i,d,X,Y,Z);

i = index for the loop
d = index for a second loop
X = double for a Cartesian system
Y = double for a Cartesian system
Z = double for a Cartesian system
```

Right now the output looks like this:

```
06 BR12   1.00001.00001.0000
```

I want it to be like the following:

```
06 BR0102   001.0000001.0000001.000
```

I know that I could just add placeholding zeros manually (if i<10, add a placeholder, etc.) but is there a more efficient way to output a placeholder zero than simply adding them in if-statements?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can zero pad with `%08.4f`, for example.  Note that the first number is the *entire* field width, not just the number of places you want before the decimal.  In your example, the `3` in `%3.4` has no effect.  If you want your last number to only have three decimal places, you'll want `%07.3f` for that one.

The `%d` formats are easier - in your case, just `%02d` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Below formatting will help you.

```
float a = 1;
int x = 1, y = 2;
printf("06 BR%02d%02d   %08.4f %08.4f %08.4f\n", x, y, a, a, a);
```

output for me is

```
06 BR0102   001.0000 001.0000 001.0000
```

Comment: Explaining it a bit would be nice.