# Print a decimal number in a particular format using setfill() in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print a decimal no. in following format : "#####+3.01"
Case: There is a decimal no (let say 3.01 in this case). I have to print it with its sign +/-  preceding with y no. of #, with some fix total width. (let say x = 10 in this case).

I tried do something like this :

> ```
>    double no = 3.01;
>    cout << setfill('#') << setw(10) ;
>    cout << setiosflags(ios::showpos);
>    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << no << endl;
> ```

But i am getting followinfg output :

> ```
>     +#####3.01
> ```

Expected Output :

> ```
>     #####+3.01
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::ostringstream puts sign in wrong location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729847/stdostringstream-puts-sign-in-wrong-location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gave me correct result. I am using a Linux machine.

Just in case it is a OS dependent problem, try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double no = 3.01;
    cout << setfill('#') << std::right<< setw(10) ;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::showpos);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << no << endl;
}
```

Comment: I think adding `std::right` is the solution. +1